# Why is the height of UITableViewCell is smaller than the height of its text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell`s, I set the height of each cell in the function `heightForRowAtIndexPath` in the fallowing way:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSStringDrawingOptions opts = (NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading);
    CGSize boundingRect = CGSizeMake(450.f, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize size = [cell.detailTextLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:boundingRect
                                                      options:opts
                                                   attributes:[cell.detailTextLabel.attributedText attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:nil]
                                                      context:nil].size;
    CGFloat height = size.height;
    size = [cell.textLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:boundingRect
                                         options:opts
                                      attributes:[cell.textLabel.attributedText attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:nil]
                                         context:nil].size;
    height += size.height;
    return height;
}
```

But the cell that I get is too small for the text, and longer text doesn't fit:

[image: if the text doesn't fit you must acquit]

The text that is written in cell is set in the following way:

```
NSString *nickName = @"some nickname"; // gets the nickname
NSString title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ wrote:", nickName];
NSString *detail = @"some text"; // gets the content of the message

[cell.textLabel setText: title];
[cell.detailTextLabel setText: detail];
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Why is the height of the cell too short?

Comment: why do you have to set the row height?? Why don't you use estimatedRowHeight ?

Comment: Maybe use Autolayout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From method `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1524729-boundingrectwithsize :

"This method returns the actual bounds of the glyphs in the string"

What is missing is the margins of the cell, which can be accessed with `cell.layoutMargins`:

```
height += cell.layoutMargins.top + cell.layoutMargins.bottom;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the boundingRect method of `NSAttributedString`  (Swift 3)

```
//change this value with the width of your UITableViewCell
let availableWidth:CGFloat = 355 

let stringBoundingRect = NSAttributedString(string: "your string").boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: availableWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: [.usesDeviceMetrics, .usesLineFragmentOrigin], context: nil)

let height = stringBoundingRect.height
```

In Objective-C:

```
// change this value with the width of your UITableViewCell
CGFloat availableWidth = 355;

NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"your string"];
CGRect stringBoundingRect = [attrStr boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(availableWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX) options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin| NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics context:nil];

CGFloat height = stringBoundingRect.size.height;
```